# find out the closest hidden input field with id ending with lkid

Tags: jquery

```
<div>

    <input id="abc_lkid" type="hidden" value="001i0000008MQKP" >
    <input id="abc_lkpld" type="hidden" value="001i00000022222P" >
    <select id="selectedAccountId" class="accSelectandlookup" style="width:250px" size="1" >
        <option value="000000000000000000">Create New Account: Pradys</option>
        <option value="111111111111111111">Attach to Existing : Ace Iron and Steel Inc.</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I need to get the value of nearest hidden field with id ending with lkid within the div holding the select

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [attribute ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
$('#selectedAccountId').siblings('input[type="hidden"][id$="lkid"]').val();
```

Gets the value of the hidden input with `id` ending `lkid` relative to your `select`

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84AHg/2/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).closest('div').find("input[id$='lkid']:hidden:first").val();
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/XNw6R/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `*=`, this means `contains in`.

```
var closestInput = $('div').find($('input[id*="lkid"]'));
```

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rkmCJ/1/)